# Glassfish javaagent instrumented class experiences NoClassDefError

Tags: glassfish, osgi, classloader, instrumentation, javaagents

I have Oracle GlassFish 3.1.2.2 (build 5) server plugged with my own javaagent.

The javaagent instruments specific classes(say servlets) by injecting a piece of bytecode which referes to classes available in javaagent.jar. When the injected fragment is getting executed, glassfish throws NoClassDefError.

I wonder the expected class is already loaded by base classloader and should be visible to the child loaders.
Tried OSGi boot delegation, but no use.
Where I'm going worng ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the javaagent.jar in domains/domain1/lib/ext solves this issue.
Hope the solution helps someone in future ..